# Can a minor (17 years old) travel from the US to the UK unaccompanied?

Tags: uk, us-citizens, minors

I am considering taking a trip to England this summer to check out a university. For money (and experience) purposes, I would prefer to travel alone. My plan is to fly on Primera Air from BOS to STN. According to Primera's site, I should be fine flying with them alone as a 17 year-old, but will entering the UK pose an issue? All I've found is a [page on gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18) that only seems to apply if you are applying for a visa, not if you are entering visa-free (as I would be from the US).

I do have friends in the UK that I would be staying with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. My kids have been doing this since they were about 15 or so, and there was never a problem. Check the airline rules about "unaccompanied minors", just to be safe, but as 17 year old, you will for all practical purposes be treated as an adult traveler.

That comes of course with the same responsibilities of an adult, i.e. you have to make sure your paperwork is in order, you know how to maneuver an airport on your own, you have money in local currency, you can figure out how to get from A to B, and you know what your options are, if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just comply with the same requirements as if you were a visa national: the rules are designed to help keep you safe and prevent child/human trafficking. Letter from your parents, proof you will be able to afford your costs while in UK, place to stay, and evidence of plans to return to USA (your return ticket and family home being there should be enough for that!)

Comment: A (slightly poorly organised) list of the documents that are recommended to bring with you can be found here https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf